# Shortcut to eject all external hard drives but not MobileBackups

Tags: keyboard, backup, applescript, external-disk, eject

So far I've been using the following AppleScript to eject all external drives at once conveniently using a shortcut:

```
tell application "Finder"
    eject (every disk)
end tell
```

This script is is stored in `/Library/Scripts` and I have assigned a shortcut to trigger it in [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).

But there's one problem. When you have **Time Machine Backups** enabled, OS X mounts a virtual `MobileBackups` volume in `/Volumes` to store **local snapshots**. This volume will be ejected alongside all the physical external volumes. I want to avoid this as this will stop local snapshots from being made (until it's mounted again at next login).

#### How can I add an exception to exclude `/Volumes/MobileBackups` in the AppleScript above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This AppleScript code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set diskList to the disks
    repeat with mountedDisk in diskList
        if name of mountedDisk is not "MobileBackups" then
            eject mountedDisk
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

ejects all mounted disks except when named `MobileBackups`, that is, `/Volumes/MobileBackups`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following instead:

```
tell application "Finder"
  eject (every disk whose ejectable is true)
end tell
```

If you have partitioned disks mounted, hold down the 
"Option" key, run your script, then release the key when done.

Comment: Any way to show a notification when disks have been successfully ejected?

Comment: Thank you, I incorporated your logic into my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

I've slightly modified this to do exclusions as a set.

```
set exceptionsList to {"MobileBackups", "startup disk", "home", "net"}
tell application "Finder"
    set diskList to the disks
    repeat with mountedDisk in diskList
        if name of mountedDisk is not in exceptionsList then
            eject mountedDisk
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you, I incorporated your logic into my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Putting Neil Ticktin's and Dickster's solutions together:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set diskList to the disks whose ejectable is true
    repeat with mountedDisk in diskList
        set mountedDiskName to the name of mountedDisk
        
        set skip to my skipDisk(mountedDiskName)
        if skip is false then
            eject mountedDisk
            log "ejected " & mountedDiskName
        else
            log skip
        end if
        
    end repeat
end tell

-- skipDisk is either `false` or a string explaining what was skipped and why
on skipDisk(diskName)
    set exceptionsList to {"TimeMachine", ".backup"}
    
    if diskName is in exceptionsList then
        return "skipped: \"" & diskName & "\" is in `exceptionsList`"
    end if
    
    repeat with exceptionDiskName in exceptionsList
        if diskName contains exceptionDiskName then
            return "skipped: \"" & diskName & "\" contains \"" & exceptionDiskName & "\""
        end if
    end repeat
    
    return false
end skipDisk
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Ady's answer [in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143421/how-to-eject-all-external-partitions-quickly/446460#446460), Here's a simpler version that worked for me.

I filtuer out the TimeMachine backups (*Example: disk "2022-09-07-113224.backup"*) be filtering out root owned volumes. Zach's approach is much more fullproof though by checking the names.

Here's what works for me.

```
tell application "Finder"
    eject (every disk whose ejectable is true and local volume is true and format is not unknown format and owner is not "system")
end tell
```

You can test which disks will be ejected in Script Editor by running

```
tell application "Finder"
    every disk whose ejectable is true and local volume is true and format is not unknown format and owner is not "system"
end tell
```