# Ejecting all network drives via Applescript/Automator/Shell?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, automation

I use the following script to attempt to eject all disks that aren't internal:

```
tell application "Finder"
    eject (disks whose ejectable is true)
end tell
```

This has the advantage of skipping volumes like `MobileBackups` as well as several others.

Unfortunately, it doesn't eject network shares.

Is there any way to get connected network shares in applescript?

As a +1, ideally this would skip things like optical disks as well.

**EDIT**: Both answers so far have shared ways to eject *specific* network disks. This, of course, is easy and I know how to do it. What I'm specifically asking for is a way to attempt to eject every disk other than system internal disks, regardless of their name.

Comment: Interestingly, I've been using something almost identical to this to eject my external drives, and it has worked like a charm until after the last time I restarted. Now I get a popup that says, `The Disk "32-digit UUID" wasn't ejected because one or more programs may be using it.` but I can't figure out what that UUID corresponds to. It is not listed in `diskutil info -all` for example. Also nothing is listed in lsof. This is on OSX High Sierra. Any suggestions?

Comment: It turns out the UUID was from Clusters (the background compression tool). It doesn't actually appear as a drive anywhere that I can see, but I finally found it in lsof.

Answer (score 2):

I use Automator. I inserted 'Get Specified Finder Items', and named the target disks that I wanted to 'Get'. Only those named get chosen, but network drives do work. I then pipe this to 'Eject Disk'.

That's it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easily done by using the `-t` option of the `umount` command. From the man page which you can read using `man umount`:

```
-t type
             Is used to indicate the actions should only be taken on filesys-
             tems of the specified type.  More than one type may be specified
             in a comma separated list.  The list of filesystem types can be
             prefixed with ``no'' to specify the filesystem types for which
             action should not be taken.  For example, the umount command:

                   umount -a -t nfs,hfs
```

So,

```
do shell script "/sbin/umount -a -t nfs,smbfs"
```

should umount all NFS and Windows/Samba shares mounted.

EDIT: You may also want to use the `-f` option to force the action. Read the man page for details.

EDIT2: Apologies, umount isn't behaving as advertised, at least on my Snow Leopard. So I'd do it like this remembering to change `msdos` to your desired filesystem type:

```
set mounts to {}
set mounts to paragraphs of (do shell script "mount | grep msdos | cut -d ' ' -f3")

# Umount non busy filesystems
repeat with mount in mounts
    set pid to (do shell script "fuser -c " & mount)
    if pid is equal to "" then
        # We use diskutil since classic unix umount cmd needs sudo/password 
        do shell script "diskutil umount " & mount
    end if
end repeat
```

HTH

Comment: How can I find out what type of filesystem a disk was mounted with?

Comment: The `mount` command will display all the mounted filesystems.  In the output, the first word after the bracket is the filesystem type.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just call the shell command..

```
do shell script "/usr/sbin/diskutil unmount /Volumes/some_network_share"
```

Note that this might fail if you have open files so you can add `force` as such

```
do shell script "/usr/sbin/diskutil unmount force /Volumes/some_network_share"
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line utility `/sbin/umount` may be another solution to what you're looking for. The Mac OS keeps an alias to each of your mounted disks in a folder /Volumes. You can use this to your advantage and amount a drive listed there:

```
$ umount /Volumes/Video
```

So you might want to create a shell script that lists the contents of /Volumes and attempts to eject them all, like this one:

```
for var in `ls /Volumes` ; do
echo Ejecting /Volumes/$var
umount /Volumes/$var
done
```

It will, however, fail to eject drives that cannot be ejected, like the current startup disk.

Answer (score 0):

This will only eject all network volumes:

```
$ find /Volumes -maxdepth 1 -not -user root -print0 | xargs -0 umount
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an AppleScript, I adapted the script posted at:
[Shortcut to eject all external hard drives but not MobileBackups](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86005/shortcut-to-eject-all-external-hard-drives-but-not-mobilebackups)

to this, and it works great.  I've placed the applet for this in my dock to use right before I unplug.

```
set exceptionsList to {"MobileBackups", "startup disk", "home", "net"}
tell application "Finder"
    set diskList to the disks
    repeat with mountedDisk in diskList
        if name of mountedDisk is not in exceptionsList then
            eject mountedDisk
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```