# Simple method to mount a named drive from the command line?

Tags: finder, applescript, command-line, bash, diskutil

To unmount a named drive from the command line I wrote a bash function which just tells the Finder via AppleScript to eject the drive:

```
eject () { osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to eject disk \"$1\"" ; }
```

However I'd like to also find a way to subsequently re-mount that drive (by name), but this seems to be somewhat more complicated, perhaps requiring the use of `diskutil` ?

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for non-encrypted drives:

```
mountall() {
    disks=$(diskutil list | grep "external, physical" | sed 's/ .*//')
    while IFS= read -r disk; do
        echo "Trying to mount disk $disk"
        diskutil mountDisk $disk
    done <<< "$disks"
}
```

For encrypted drives, you'd need to get the UUID of the drive by running `diskutil coreStorage list` and looking near `Logical Volume Family` for a the UUID of the drive that looks like `ABCDEF-123456-GEHIJK-7890...`, and then run:

```
diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume <UUID>
```

But this will prompt you for a password, which may be more troublesome than disconnecting and reconnecting the drive.

Comment: Thanks - I’ll give that a try!

Comment: Sure, and if it does work, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: It almost works, but (a) if seems to mount the EFI partition on each volume and (b) it doesn't mount a volume on a FAT32 SD card.